# Play Framework 2 URL without port

Tags: url, binding, playframework-2.0, port

this must be a really easy question to answer but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I have a play framework 2 application that I want to put in production on Windows Server 2008. I only have ports 80 8080 and 443 open to the outside.
I start my play application with this:

```
play -Dhttp.port=80 "run 80"
```

but I get an error that says that "failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:80.
I can do:

```
play -Dhttp.port=8080 "run 8080"
```

and this works, I can get outside access to my web application by typing http://sometestingurl.pt:8080/index but I don't want to have the port number on my URL. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to running your application in production mode, the advice from Play is to [not use the run command](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production), but instead use the `start` script that is generated for you after running the `dist` task.

Once you've run the `dist` task and unzipped your application on the server, the following command should start it and bind to port 80:

```
start -Dhttp.port=80
```

Comment: The Play Framework currently doesn't officially support production mode on Windows (i.e. the start and stage tasks) so you'll have to run the app in dev mode. [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have another application running on port 80. If it's Windows Server then there's a good chance IIS is running (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321141 for details on how to turn it off).

As well as configuring the Play application itself to run on port 80, you can also set up a frontend web server as described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer. This technique has the added advantage that it enables you to run several Play applications on port 80 using virtual hosts.

One other thing...it's not possible to at the moment to run a Play app in production mode on Windows so you'll have to use the "run" command (or move the app to a Unix box). Further details here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production

Answer (score 0):

I am using play version 2.2.2. The following solution is tested on CentOS 6.5:

If you have the source code folder on the server:

1. cd into your project directory
2. `sudo play "start -Dhttp.port=80"`

You will likely run into an error `sudo: play: command not found`. To fix this problem, you do this:

1. 'nano /etc/sudoers'
2. add “#” in front of “secure_path"  (which comments out this line)
3. then, go back to your project dir and repeat step 2) `sudo play "start -Dhttp.port=80"`

If you want to deploy your code onto a production server, this is what you do:

1. cd into your project dir
2. `play dist` -> this command will generate a .zip file in the target/universal dir.
3. transfter this .zip file to your production server
4. unzip the .zip file `unzip yourfile.zip`
5. after the file is unzip:
   `cd your_unzipped_folder/bin`
6. There should be a file with the same name as your application name. To start it up:
   `sudo nohup ./yourapp -Dhttp.port=80`